# Add an arraylist to 2d arraylist in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, arraylist

I have a 2D arraylist which I want to fill it with several 1D arraylists. My code is the following:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(); 
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

while (ts2.next()) {
    list.add( ts2.getString("userName");
    list.add(ts2.getString("userId"));  
    array.add(list);
    list.clear();
}
```

I have noticed that `list.clear()` deletes the elements from the `list` however also deletes the element from the `array`. In the end, both `array` and `list` are empty. How can I add list in `array` and clear the `list` after  `array.add(list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone the list:

```
array.add(list.clone());
```

Or you can instantiate the list object within the loop itself:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(); 

    while (ts2.next()) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add( ts2.getString("userName");
        list.add(ts2.getString("userId"));  
        array.add(list);
    }
```

Then you wouldn't even need to clear it.

Comment: I got this message: The method add(ArrayList<String>) in the type ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Comment: Try to cast the object as an arraylist: `array.add((ArrayList<String>)list.clone());`

Comment: array.add(list.clone()); don't work

Comment: @adeeliqbal Not sure why it wouldn't work. You're adding an arraylist into an arraylist of arraylists.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
    ArrayList<String[]> arr = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String[] str = new String[2];
    while (ts2.next()) {
        str[0] = ts2.getString("userName");
        str[1] = ts2.getString("userId");  
        arr.add(str);
    }
```

if you would an arraylist also:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    while (ts2.next()) {
        ArrayList<String> arrString = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrString.add(ts2.getString("userName"));
        arrString.add(ts2.getString("userId"));  
        arr.add(arrString);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new instance of `ArrayList<>` to be added in the existing one.

```
while (ts2.next()) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(ts2.getString("userName"));
    list.add(ts2.getString("userId"));  
    array.add(list);
}
```

However the better approach is to map these values into a new instance of a class.

```
List<MyClass> = new ArrayList<>();

while (ts2.next()) {
    MyClass i = new MyClass(ts2.getString("userName"), ts2.getString("userId"));
    array.add(i);
}
```